# Practicallity of winding inductor for high current DC to DC boost converter?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, inductor

This is a very basic question, not about the various designs of DC DC switched mode power supplies, but the practicalities of the inductor involved. If you want to boost from 12 volts to a much higher voltage then you have to pull a lot of current from the 12 Volt supply, lets say 10 amperes for the sake of argument.

You don't see many inductors which will take 10 amperes and if you wanted to wind one yourself you'd have to use pretty heavy gauge wire, which would be very difficult, if not practically impossible,  to actually wind around a toriod.

I'm assuming a switched mode power supply, but maybe that's not the way you would boost to much higher voltages.

Comment: Be careful about "heavy wire" when winding magnetics. The AC resistance of the winding increases as the wire diameter increases due to proximity effect. Using bunched or Litz wire reduces AC resistance.

Comment: It depends on the output voltage, but if it is difficult to get an inductor for a boost converter, it may make more sense to use some other topology, such as flyback or forward converter which requires a transformer instead of an inductor.

Comment: "but maybe that's not the way you would boost to much higher voltages?" -- do you have a specific output voltage in mind?  Usually you go with boost up to about 10:1 ratio, and with a flyback for 5:1 or more -- and yes, there's overlap: between 5:1 and 10:1 it's a judgement call.

Comment: Digikey has thousands of inductors in stock rated for more than 10A, so not hard at all to find them.  Usually though you wouldn't use a boost converter for very high ratios.

Comment: Thank you for the 10:1. I was thinking about how inverters would work, so in 240V Mains land if you were going from 12V DC up to 240DC, if you had a device that would work with DC. I assumed a heating element wouldn't care DC or AC. I looked at a kettle for boiling water which is 2500W, that's a lot of current out of a 12V battery, even if you used a transformer it'd have to cope with a lot of current. 12V DC inverters are obviously available, so this is possible but the currents involved are high on the 12V side.

Answer (score 1):

"You don't see many Inductors which will take 10 Amps". You are not looking in the right place! Just enter "toroidal inductor" in a site like Aliexpress and you will get a whole page of them, some rated at 10A. Similarly over 300 hits on eBay and some 400+ on Farnell UK, some rated at up to 30A. Other sites are available.

Obviously the value of the inductor depends on the design of your power supply, but you should find something that would suit.

To wind them yourself (the same sites sell bare cores) would be tedious as you need to pass all the unwound wire through the core for each turn whilst keeping the turns neat and tidy, but not impossible as most of this type of inductor seem not to require too many turns if you look inside a commercial SMPS.

The bottom line is, however, unless you are building this power supply as a design / learning exercise or it's very special, then a ready-made unit from one of the sites would be cheaper and a lot less hassle.